# How to give custom response if user input other data types?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
response = input("Do you want some food? (Y/N): ")

if response == "Y":
    print("Come! There is pizza for you")
elif response == "N":
    print("Alright, let us do Sisha instead.")
elif response == range(999):
    print("The required response is Y/N.")
else:
    print("I do not understand the prompt")
```

**Q1: How to give feedback when user input numbers instead of string?**

A1: I take a look in python documentation but it seems that range cannot be used in if statement?

I try to modify the code by stating

```
deret_angka = int or float
for n in deret_angka:
  print("The required response is Y/N.")
```

and third ifs condition to:

```
elif response == deret_angka:
    print("The required response is Y/N.")
```

But got TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

**Q2: How to give Y & N value even if its lower case y/n?**

A2: I tried to put "Y" or "y" but it doesn't work and just passed to next if condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you can give feedback in many ways in python.
Let's say the user typed a number so we can try to convert the `type` of the input and see if it raises an error like that:

```
response = input("Do you want some food? (Y/N): ")
try:
    float(response)
    int(response)
except ValueError: #it a string or a bool
    print("The required response is Y/N.")
```

If you want to check on a number in a specific range you can do it like that:

```
if response in [range(999)]:
    pass
```

You can't check just `range(999)` because it is an object. You need to convert this object to a list to loop over it.

To check lower case you can do it in some ways:

```
response = input("Do you want some food? (Y/N): ")

if response in ['Y', 'y']:
    pass
elif response in ['N', 'n']:
    pass

#or like that:

if response.lower == 'y': # Just convert the input to lower
    pass
if response.upper == 'N': # You can also do this and vice versa and convert to upper and check.
    pass
```